# Parsing Json differs between PowerShell and GitHub "run" statement

Tags: json, github-actions

I am trying to extract a single property from a json file. I am planning to save it off to an env. variable to use in a compare later. What works at the PS command line does not produce the same results through Github workflow run on a windows-latest runner (github hosted).

```
$json = Get-Content integration-manifest.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.[some_property]
```

This command in the shell shows me the value I am expecting for this property. In GitHub action, only the command line appears and not the output.

How can I get just the one value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```yaml
- name: Read json
  id: read-json
  shell: pwsh
  run: |
    $json = Get-Content yourfile.json | ConvertFrom-Json
    echo "::set-output name=prop::$(echo $json.prop)"

- run: echo ${{ steps.read-json.outputs.prop}}
```